# Measurable set on Manifold.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In my textbook, we have the following definition,

> If $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. We say that a set $A\subset M$ is measurable if, for any chart $U$, the intersection $A\cap U$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $U$.

What really means this? A chart $U$ on $M$ is any couple $(U,\varphi)$ where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism of $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. So, if for any chart $U$, the intersection $A\cap U\implies \varphi(A\cap U)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Lesbesgue measurable set in $U$?

And, also says that

> The family of all measurable sets in $M$ forms a $\sigma-$álgebra.

But I don't see how this form an $\sigma-$algebra, i.e., is the union of measurable set measurable?. Thanks!

Comment: For  a sigma-algebra one needs closure under **countable** unions.

Comment: I write a chart as $c = (\mathrm{U}, \varphi, n)$ where $\mathrm{U}$ is an open subset of the manifold and $n$ is the dimension of the chart. Then, what measurability means is that $\varphi(\mathrm{A} \cap \mathrm{U})$ is a Lebuesgue measurable set in $\mathbf{R}^n.$

Comment: @WillM. and these open $U$ (their collection) form a $\sigma$-algebra correct? closed under complement and (countable) union.

Comment: No. Because, in general, the complement of an open set is not open.